# Unable to install extension for Visual Studio Community 2015 using .vsix file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I've been trying to install an extension for visual Studio Community 2015 using a .vsix file. When I double-click it, nothing happens. I've also tried opening it with "Visual Studio Version Selector" using "Open With..", but even then nothing happens.

After some searching, I found that the `.vsix` file can also be installed using *Developer Command Prompt for VS2015*, but even that didn't help.

Initially I thought that maybe the extension is faulty, but the same thing happens if try to install any other `.vsix` extension.

Note: The extensions that I have tried to installing  are `UnrealVS.vsix` and `Roslyn_SDK.vsix`

Comment: I have the same problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happened at the first place. But the problem was fixed after I reinstalled visual studio 2015 community.
 Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be a common issue, as the standard double click operation over a VSIX file in the File Explorer will fail to install ANY Visual Studio 2015 .vsix extension. It appears that this operation requires administrative permissions. The issue here is that it is not possible to indicate to "install as administrator".

The only way to install the extension was executing the `VSIXInstaller.exe` using a CMD Window as Administrator and passing the VSIX file as parameters. The procedure I used was:

1. Open a CMD Window as Administrator
2. Go to Common7\IDE folder of your VS 2015 installation:

   ```
   CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
   ```
3. Execute the installer passing your VSIX file name as parameter:

   ```
   VSIXInstaller.exe c:\YourVSIXFile.
   ```
4. The installer should now start the installation process for your VSIX extension. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Normally, .vsix is associated with VSIXInstaller. By default it is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe`

Comment: But how to use the VSIXInstaller.exe?

Comment: Just run it with the .vsix as the parameter: VSIXInstaller.exe UnrealVS.vsix

Answer (score 1):

Try to unzip the .vsix file and have a look of the vsixmanifest see the InstallationTarget supports 14.0 or not.

If no add InstallationTarget Version="14.0" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community"

Comment: or you can try to run it in cmd with administrator right

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before and the only way I was able to install extensions is by using the following steps:

1. Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online
2. Search the extension name
3. Click Download

This will download and install the extension cleanly for you. 
some of the extensions will take you to page where you download the .vsix which you have to install it as the other comments describe.